# Kaplan-Yorke dimension when all Lyapunov exponents are positive or the system is 1-dimensional

Tags: hausdorff-dimension, chaos

The Lyapunov/Kaplan-Yorke dimension $D_{KY}$ can be calculated using the Lyapunov Exponents of an n-dimensional dynamical system, as shown in the [relevant Scholarpedia entry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kaplan-Yorke_dimension).
If $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>\dots>\lambda_n$ are the Lyapunov Exponents of the system in decreasing order, then:
\begin{equation}
D_{KY} = k + \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\lambda_i}{|{\lambda_{k+1}|}}
\end{equation}
Where $k \leq n$ is the largest integer so that the sum of the first k Lyapunov Exponents is positive.

My questions are:

1. How is this definition interpreted for 1-dimensional chaotic systems, like the Logistic map $4x(1-x)$ with a positive Lyapunov Exponent $\lambda_1 = \log 2$? Here $k=1$ and there is no $\lambda_2$.
2. How is it interpreted for n-dimensional systems where the sum of the first Lyapunov exponents is positive, as those that have $\lambda_n$>0? Then $k=n$ and $\lambda_{k+1}$ is not defined.

I couldn't spot anything about these 2 edge cases in the [original paper from Kaplan and Yorke](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0064306) (page 204) or in any other places.